What is the adjoint bundle of groups $P\times_{G}G$?
It is said that G acts on itself by conjugation. I am familiar with another type of adjoint bundle in which a representation of G on a vector space is given. Can someone explain the differences and give some intuitions?
In What sense is it the endomorphism bundle of P?

You say "It is said that …", so presumably you are asking a question about a specific reference. What is that reference? (One possible meaning is that this is just the quotient of $P \times G$ by the equivalence relation $(p, g) \sim (p\cdot h, h^{-1}g h)$ over all $p \in P$ and $g, h \in G$.)

One obvious difference is that your second adjoint bundle is a vector bundle, but your first one isn't.

In general, if $P$ is a principal $G$-bundle over a base $B$, and $X$ a space with an action of $G$, then one can form the associated bundle $P\times_G X$. By definition, this is the quotient of $P\times X$ by the relation $(p,x) \sim (p\cdot g, g^{-1}\cdot x)$. In particular, one can take $X=G$ with the conjugation action. On the other hand, if $X$ happens to be a linear representation, then the associated bundle is a vector bundle. In particular, one can take $X=\mathfrak g =Lie(G)$ - this is also sometimes called the adjoint bundle.

The group of global sections of the adjoint bundle $P^\mathrm{ad}:= P\times_{G} G^{\mathrm{ad}}$ ($G^{\mathrm{ad}}$ denotes $G$ with the adjoint action on itself) with pointwise multiplication—as $P^\mathrm{ad}$ is a bundle of groups—is isomorphic to the group of automorphisms of the bundle $P$ (see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_group_(mathematics), but it's not a very thorough reference). In the case when $G$ is abelian, this is the same thing as functions from the base space to $G$, and these act on the bundle pointwise.

Thus you should more think of $P^\mathrm{ad}$ as being more related to automorphisms, not endomorphisms. Mathematicians call this group of sections the 'gauge group' of the bundle, though in physics language this usually refers to $G$ itself. (I have been in a talk where someone asked a question using one version of this terminology, and the speaker thought it was the other one, and it was frustrating for them and for me, as neither understood what the other meant, and I could tell why)
